# Как релизовать каскадное удаление в данном случае?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

**Нужно реализовать возможность системы подписок с помощью ef core 3.1**

Имеется два класса,один с юзерами другой с подписками,каждый юзер может быть и публикатором и подписчиком соответственно.
В настройке связи many-to-many проблем нет,но вот при настройке удаления компилятор ссылается на multiply cascade paths. Если поставить одно из свойств на Restrict база данных инициализируется,но при удалении юзера ключ которого есть в restrict поле происходит та же ошибка.

**Как изменить код или структуру таблиц чтоб сделать возможным подписку юзеров,а также правильное удаление всех связанных записей при удалении самого юзера?**

> **Сущность юзера:**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HashCode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subscribe> Followers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subscribe> Publishers { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        Publishers = new List<Subscribe>();
        Followers = new List<Subscribe>();

    }


}
```

> **Сущность подписок**:

```
public class Subscribe
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int FollowerId { get; set; }
    public User Follower { get; set; }
    public int PublisherId { get; set; }
    public User Publisher { get; set; }

}
```

> **Контекст базы данных(здесь основная проблема):**

```
public class MDContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subscribe> Subscribes { get; set; }


        public MDContext(DbContextOptions<MDContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();

//На данном этапе разработки удаление базы не страшно

            Database.EnsureCreated();

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Subscribe>().HasKey(s => new { s.FollowerId, s.PublisherId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Subscribe>()
                        .HasOne(s => s.Follower)
                        .WithMany(f => f.Publishers)
                        .HasForeignKey(s => s.FollowerId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Subscribe>()
                        .HasOne(s => s.Publisher)
                        .WithMany(p => p.Followers)
                        .HasForeignKey(s => s.PublisherId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);






        }
    }
```

Comment: на крайний случай можно сделать две таблицы UserFollowers(UserId, FollowerId) и UserPublishers(UserId, PublisherId)